# Spring Cloud Gateway not routing (404 for any request)

Tags: spring, docker-compose, spring-cloud, gateway

I've been trying to create a docker-compose stack with Spring Cloud Gateway, Eureka, a config service and some micro services. Those services start and work on their own, exposed ports, the config service works and Eureka registers those services. But I can't get Spring Cloud Gateway to work.

The service starts correctly (or at least there are no errors in the log) and when I remote into the container I'm able to request the service I want to call, but If I try the request it via the configured route I'm receiving an 404.

My gateway config (I combined the config service config and the bootstrap.yml for convenience):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://config-service:8080 
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discovery-service:8061/eureka/
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} %m%n"
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: employee-service
        predicates:
        - "Path=/employee/**"
        filters:
        - StripPrefix=1
        uri: "http://employee-service:8080"
```

I'm pretty sure I just misunderstood some trivial thing and I'm just a click away from success, but ... I just can't find it.

What I expect to happen:

- I navigate to http://localhost:8080/employee/api/v1/employees
- The gateway routes the request to http://employee-service:8080/api/v1/employees (which works if called from the gateway container via curl)
- I receive the correct response in my browser

My containers:

```
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 8088/tcp                           employee-app_gateway-service_1
8088/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5082->5005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8082->8080/tcp   employee-app_employee-service_1
8088/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8011->8061/tcp                           employee-app_discovery-service_1
8088/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8012->8080/tcp                           employee-app_config-service_1
```

Comment: what do you get if you type http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees in your browser ?

Comment: The employee service is exposed on 8082, so it would be http://localhost:8082/api/v1/employees, but then I see ... oh, I think I understand. Let me try this

Comment: No change (I set the uri to http://localhost:8082 which is accessible from the host). Still a 404 error

Comment: let me clear the thing, what is your REST Controller name and the name of REST method that you are trying to hit?

Comment: The controller is the EmployeeController with a RequestMapping of "api/v1/employees", the method maps on "" and it works as intended. It's the gateway I'm having trouble with. It fails even if I try to route to a public url.

Comment: I'm not sure I could diagnose the problem without a project that recreates the problem.

Comment: Found it. Typical Layer 8 issue :-|

I'll post a fix...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to be one of my most shameful layer 8 issues. boostrap.yml != bootstrap.yml. I did spend three days on this. I'm not sure if I'm angry on myself or ashamed. I hope you'll have a laugh on me :-)